# Merge two XTS objects one with logicals

Tags: r, xts

I have two XTS objects, both of same dimensions, one with logical operators (TRUE/FALSE) and the other with integers. I'm trying to subset the integers to only show the datapoints where the logical operators XTS object is TRUE.

XTS_logical

```
DATE       Col1      Col2
20170630   TRUE      FALSE
20170731   FALSE     TRUE
20170831   TRUE      TRUE
```

XTS_integers

```
DATE       Col1      Col2
20170630    5         6
20170731    2         3
20170831    5         9
```

XTS desired result

```
DATE       Col1      Col2
20170630    5         NA
20170731    NA        3
20170831    5         9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that the data in an xts object is a matrix. So you can just use matrix calculations and multiply XTS_logical with XTS_integers

```
XTS_outcome <- XTS_logical * XTS_integers
XTS_outcome 
           Col1 Col2
2017-06-30    5    0
2017-07-31    0    3
2017-08-31    5    9
```

If you want the 0 as NA's you can do `XTS_outcome[XTS_outcome == 0] <- NA`.

data:

```
XTS_logical <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), .Dim = 3:2, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Col1", "Col2")), index = structure(c(1498780800, 
1501459200, 1504137600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")

XTS_integers <- structure(c(5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 9L), .Dim = 3:2, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Col1", "Col2")), index = structure(c(1498780800, 
1501459200, 1504137600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `XTS_logical` directly as the index of the cells you want changed.

```
XTS_integers[!XTS_logical] <- NA
#            Col1 Col2
# 2017-06-30    5   NA
# 2017-07-31   NA    3
# 2017-08-31    5    9
```

This way any `0`s originally in `XTS_integers` won't be changed to `NA`.